# Permutations without repetition and with indistinguishable objects

Tags: combinatorics

I am a bit confused on how these two cases are different. I will be giving an example to explain what I don't understand:

Permutations without repetition:
How many permutations of the letters ABCDEFGH contain the string ABC ?

We have a set with 6 elements we can pick, if we pick one then we have 5 possibilities for the next one and so one, therefore  the solution is :

6!= 720 possible permutations.

Permutations with repetition :
How many permutations of the letters ABCDEFGH contain the string ABC and contains 6 elements ?

We have 6 possibilities for the first pick, 6 for the second (since we allow repetition) and so on. Therefore the result is :

6^6= 46656.

I full understand both cases.

What I don't understand is the case when we study permutation for indistinguishable objects. Example:

How many different strings can be made by reordering the letters of the word SUCCESS?

Initially I thought to solve it like I did for the permutation without repetition, which would be we have a set with n elements and need to pick r from it. But the problem here is that we have a set that contains the same element 2 or 3 times. So it is not the first case. Then I though, since there are repetitive elements maybe I can try the case of permutation with repetition for building a string with 7 letters, but that wasn't either the correct approach.
Apparently the solution is of the form:

C(7,3)C(4,2)C(2,1)C(1,1)=420.

But the expression of the form C(n,r) represent the nr. of r-combinations of a set with n elements. Which is the case of combination without repetition.

My question is : Are non-repetitive/repetitive and distinguishable/indistinguishable objects 2 different things?

Comment: What does "Permutations with repetition" mean?

Comment: using the same element from the set as many times as you like, or depending from the condition.

Comment: That would not look like a *permutation* to me

Comment: well that's the definition of a permutation with repetition. You have a set of n elements, and you need to pick r times for that set. Since it has repetition it means every time you pick, you have n possibilities, since you put the element that you picked back again and select again. That would amass into n^r possible permutations. Which makes sense

Comment: The second part: How many permutations of the letters ABCDEFGH contain the string ABC and contains $6$ elements? How did you get $6^6$? That does not seem correct.

Comment: taking ABC as one element then you have additionally D E F G H, in total you have a set of 6 elements, and you can pick 6 times. 6^6

Comment: The string ABC fills three spaces.  If you include the string ABC, then you only have three more spaces to fill, so your answer to the second part does not make sense.

Comment: The ABC is taken as a single object, because you can combine the letters however you want, but the ABC stays intact. The example is in my book, and also done in the lecture, so this is not the main point of my question. Consider the ABC= X and you have D E F G H. You have 6 objects to choose and arrange them when permutation is allowed. That's 6^6

Comment: Even if that is the case and you take ABC as X, which is not clear from how the question is written, $6^6$ contains many arrangements where X is missing.